# How to pin .desktop file to dock?

Tags: gnome-shell, .desktop, ubuntu-dock, favorites

I want to pin a .desktop file to dock. That file opens terminal and runs the command `npm start`. It opens an application, so Right Click > "Add to favorite" doesn't work. Any ideas how to pin that type of file?

Comment: If a .desktop file is created, it must be visible in show applications. You can drag that from there and drop in dock

Comment: @Kulfy You forgot to mention the .desktop file needs to be placed in a correct directory first (e.g. `~/.local/share/applications/`) for that.

Comment: @pomsky Yeah I forgot that. Thank you for mentioning.